# Multi canvas drawing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

> I am building a paint tool application.I am using two canvases. One for loading a background image and one for do the painting. Painting canvas is placed over the other one. I used two canvases because i don't want the eraser tool to take effect on the image. On my  code y position drawn by the application is not always accurate. In most cases the line is drawn higher than the actual drawn path.

```
var baseCanvas,baseContext,canvasObj,context;
var lastX,lastY,mouseX,mouseY;
var isMouseDown = false;
var mode = "pen";

$(window).load(function()
{
    baseCanvas = document.getElementById("imageCanvas");    
    baseContext = baseCanvas.getContext("2d");
    baseContext.strokeStyle = 'Black';
    baseContext.fillStyle = "skyBlue";
    baseContext.lineWidth = 5;
    baseContext.fillRect(0, 0, baseCanvas.width, baseCanvas.height);

    canvasObj = document.getElementById("drawingCanvas");
    context = canvasObj.getContext("2d");
    context.strokeStyle = 'Black';  
    context.lineCap = "round";
    context.lineJoin = "round";
    context.lineWidth = 2;          

function handleMouseDown(e) {
    mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - $('#drawingCanvas').offset().left);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - $('#drawingCanvas').offset().top);
    lastX = mouseX;
    lastY = mouseY;
    isMouseDown = true;
}

function handleMouseUp(e) {
    mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - $('#drawingCanvas').offset().left);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - $('#drawingCanvas').offset().top);
    isMouseDown = false;
}

function handleMouseOut(e) {
    mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - $('#drawingCanvas').offset().left);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - $('#drawingCanvas').offset().top);
    isMouseDown = false;
}

function handleMouseMove(e) {
    mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - $('#drawingCanvas').offset().left);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - $('#drawingCanvas').offset().top);
    if (isMouseDown) {
        context.beginPath();
        if (mode == 'pen') {
            context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
            context.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
            context.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
            context.stroke();
        } else {
            context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
            context.arc(lastX, lastY, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
            context.fill();
        }
        lastX = mouseX;
        lastY = mouseY;
    }
}

$(document).on('mousedown',$("#drawingCanvas"),function (e) {
    handleMouseDown(e);
});
$(document).on('mousemove',$("#drawingCanvas"),function (e) {
    handleMouseMove(e);
});
$(document).on('mouseup',$("#drawingCanvas"),function (e) {
    handleMouseUp(e);
});
$(document).on('mouseout',$("#drawingCanvas"),function (e) {
    handleMouseOut(e);
});
});

function setCanvas(imageFile)
{
        var base_image = new Image();
        base_image.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(imageFile[0]);
        baseContext.save();
        baseContext.clearRect(0, 0, baseCanvas.width, baseCanvas.height);              
        baseContext.beginPath();
        base_image.onload = function()
        {
            baseContext.drawImage(base_image,0,0, $('#imageCanvas').width(), $('#imageCanvas').height());
            baseContext.restore(); 
        }       
}
```

Comment: The issue is occuring after scrolling the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you scroll the browser window, you need to adjust for that scrolling.

Here's how:

```
var scrollAdjustment=$("html,body").scrollTop();

mouseY+=scrollAdjustment;
```

And if you scroll horizontally, you would need to adjust for horizontal scrolling too.

BTW, since the canvas offset doesn't change, you could pre-calculate the canvas offsets one time instead of calculating it each time in your event handlers.

In your setup up top:

```
    var canvasOffset=$("#drawingCanvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
```

And in your event handlers:

```
    var scrollAdjustment=$("html,body").scrollTop();
    mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
    mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY+scrollAdjustment);
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided you are using the clientX, clientY properties of your mouse events, and that you hooked the events on the window, you should getBoundingClientRect on your canvas to know its top and left position, then substract them.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect

Rq : You might think also about hooking the events on the canvas.